# INNER JOIN table to get MIN value from duplicate id records

Tags: mysql

Trying to join the tables to get the MIN value of each record, the following table info:

**tblProduct*

```
prodId  title       description
-------------------------------
1001    title001    desc001
1002    title002    desc002
1003    title003    desc003
```

**tblPriceVariant*

```
prodId  minOrder    pricePcs
----------------------------
1001    10          10000
1001    20          7500
1001    30          5000
1002    100         50000
1002    200         40000
1003    10          2500
```

The query I tried, but the results of the both not what I want:

```
SELECT tblProduct.prodId, tblProduct.title, tblPriceVariant.pricePcs
FROM tblProduct INNER JOIN tblPriceVariant ON tblProduct.prodId=tblPriceVariant.prodId
```

And:

```
SELECT tblProduct.prodId, tblProduct.title, MIN(tblPriceVariant.pricePcs)
FROM tblProduct INNER JOIN tblPriceVariant ON tblProduct.prodId=tblPriceVariant.prodId
```

**Expected result**:

```
prodId  title       pricePcs
----------------------------
1001    title001    5000
1002    title002    40000
1003    title003    2500
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery to make it.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT MIN(pricePcs) 
        FROM tblPriceVariant pv
        WHERE p.prodId = pv.prodId) pricePcs
FROM tblProduct p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f077e5/2/0)**:

```
| prodId |    title | pricePcs |
|--------|----------|----------|
|   1001 | title001 |     5000 |
|   1002 | title002 |    40000 |
|   1003 | title003 |     2500 |
```

Comment: It worked, but why all column the `tblProduct` table show? I want only `prodId` and `title` for this case. Is it possible?

Comment: @frianH if you want to get `prodId` and `title `, you can try to `SELECT prodId,title` instead of `SELECT *`

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT prodId, tblProduct.title, minprices.pricePcs
FROM tblProduct
JOIN ( SELECT prodId, MIN(pricePcs) pricePcs
       FROM tblPriceVariant
       GROUP BY prodId ) minprices USING (prodId)
```

Comment: It worked, but why all column the `tblProduct` table show? I want only `prodId` and `title` for this case. Is it possible?

Comment: @frianH Replace the asterisk with the `table.column` names for needed columns only. The same about D-Shih's answer.

Comment: Tried to replace the asterisk, but getting error, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Still error `#1054 - Unknown column 'tblPriceVariant.pricePcs' in 'field list'`, btw thanks.

Comment: @frianH Misprint. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is almost correct, but you forgot the `group by` clause:

```
select
  tblProduct.prodId,
  tblProduct.title,
  min(tblPriceVariant.pricePcs)
from
  tblProduct inner join tblPriceVariant
  on tblProduct.prodId=tblPriceVariant.prodId
group by
  tblProduct.prodId,
  tblProduct.title
```